# @XmlRootElement annotation to read into model

Tags: java, xml, rest, spring-boot

I am trying to read a `MediaType.APPLICATION_XML` data into model class for consuming Rest API.

**Example: Code fragment**

```
 @PostMapping(value = "test/{id}/updateSome", consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
 public ResponseEntity<String> updateSome(@PathVariable String id,
                @RequestBody SomeModel reqBody) { ... }
```

**Model:**

```
 @Data
 @XmlRootElement(name = "TYPES")
 class SomeModel {
    private String  x;
    private String  y;
 }
```

**Rest API XML Body:**

```
<TYPES>
  <TYPE>
     <x>3</x>
     <y>5</y>
  </TYPE>
</TYPES>
```

**Error:**

*When @XmlRootElement(name = "TYPES")*

```
(x=null, y=null)
```

*When @XmlRootElement(name = "TYPE")*

> "status": 400,
>        "error": "Bad Request",
>        "exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
>        "message": "Could not unmarshal to [class com.model.SomeModel]: unexpected element (uri:\"\", local:\"TYPES\"). Expected elements are
>   <{}TYPE>; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException:
>   unexpected element (uri:\"\", local:\"TYPES\"). Expected elements are
>   <{}TYPE>",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out.

Created Two Model class and used `@XmlElement` annotations.

Model 1 :

```
 @Data
 @XmlRootElement(name = "TYPES")
 @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
 class SomeModel {

    @XmlElement(name = "TYPE")
    private SomeOtherModel[] type;

 }
```

Model 2 :

```
 @Data
 @XmlRootElement(name = "TYPE")
 @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
 class SomeOtherModel {

     private String  x;
     private String  y;

 }
```

> Got values as expected (x=3, y=5)

Answer (score 0):

in your api you are expecting

```
<TYPES>
  <x>..
  <y>...
```

The additional  is not recognized.

Comment: Say suppose i have multiple <type> inside a <types> , then how do i read that

Comment: to do this you need a wrapper class which contains a list of SomeModel, check this answer for list of xml https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28293973/spring-4-rest-program-to-return-a-list-in-xml-using-jaxb